# Is &#x10; a valid character in XML?

Tags: python, xml

On this data:

```
<row Id="37501" PostId="135577" Text="...uses though.&#x10;"/>
```

I'm getting an error with the Python sax parser:

```
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException:
comments.xml:29776:332: reference to invalid character number
```

I trimmed the example; 332 points to "&#x10;".

Is the parser correct in rejecting this character?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As others have stated, you probably meant `&#10;`. The reason why `&#x10;` (0x10 = 10h = 16) is invalid is that it's explicitly excluded by the XML 1.0 standard: (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Char)

```
Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

Comment: Yep, I double-checked the header, it's version="1.0".  thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`&#10;` is the linefeed character, which seems to be the intent.

`&#x10;` would be the same as `&#16;` (10 hex is 16 decimal) and would refer to the DLE (data link escape) character.

DLE is a [transmission control character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#Transmission_control) used to control the interpretation of data being transmitted.