# XML Parsing with XMLSerialize, invalid characters 0x10

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

So I am trying to retrieve some data over a socket from an old game which communicates using XML. When a message from the game comes down the line it reads something like this:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><message><type>SERVER</type><user>TestDeleteOrKillMe</user><cmd>PRIVATE_MSG</cmd><host>65.255.81.81</host><msg>57</msg></message>
```

However, what you cannot see here because this post will not display the characters is that after the number 57 in the msg tags there are two 0x10 characters, displayed as empty boxes. These boxes have the purpose of delineating parameters sent to and from the server. For example the number 57 cooresponds to a message code which contains variables then after the 0x10 there the contents of the variables are sent.

My problem is that using XmlSerialize to serialize the bytes pulled from the buffer yields me an invalid character related error, namely:

```
 {"'', hexadecimal value 0x10, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 135."}
```

The question is how can I get around this? Is there a way to configure the Serializer to accept this character or some hack to make this work?

Comment: Sure we will help you ,Please show us your code.

Comment: @Sudhakar in this particular case code is not necessary since it is well known issue with `XmlSerializer` to blindly write values and as result to produce invalid XML. The workaround - provide alternative fields for all fields that contain characters that are invalid in XML and serialize/deserialize as Base64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible problem is 0x10 is explicitly excluded by XML 1.0 standard. See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998950/is-x10-a-valid-character-in-xml).
You can try changing to XML 1.1; otherwise you may have to "manually" parse the XML yourself, or at least do a replacement (replace 0x10 with vertical pipe for example) before deserializing.

Comment: +0: suggesting to use XML 1.1 is not very useful due to lack of support in .Net. Also even 1.1 does not allow `0` which can happen too. The standard way around is Base64 all fields that can have non-text values.